# append function and nullptr not working

Tags: c++

So I traced this out and the commented section is giving my the problem, I am at the end of my link list, and I want to change the nullptr, to the new node *q but I keep returning the original link list without the newly appended Node.

```
Node* append( int x, Node* p ) { 

Node *q=new Node;
Node *head=p;

if(p==nullptr) {
    p=q;
    q->value=x;
}

while (p!=nullptr) {
    p=p->next;
}
//arrived at NULL ptr
q=p->next; //<---this is causing my program to crash.
q->value=x;
q->next=nullptr;

return head;
```

}

Comment: I'd prefer `if (!p)` to `if (p == nullptr)` and `while (p)` to `while (p != nullptr)`. Anyway, you loop until `p` is a null pointer and then dereference it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chris already told you what the problem is. Walking a pointer to null, then dereferencing it, you're going to get what you asked for: undefined behavior

This will do what you want, with considerably less code.

```
Node* append( int x, Node* p ) 
{ 
    Node **pp = &p;
    while (*pp)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    *pp = new Node;
    (*pp)->value = x;       // this really should be a Node::Node() parameter
    (*pp)->next = nullptr;  // ... and this should be set in Node::Node as well

    return p;
}
```

and it would be even simpler if you make `Node::Node(int x)` reasonably intelligent. For example, with a `Node` like:

```
struct Node
{
    int val;
    Node *next;

    Node(int val) : val(val), next() {}
};
```

You can then simply do this:

```
Node* append( int x, Node* p ) 
{ 
    Node **pp = &p;
    while (*pp)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    *pp = new Node(x);
    return p;
}
```